# Will istream::get() with no parameters return whitespace?

Tags: c++, whitespace, istream

This seems like a really simple question, but I can't find the answer anywhere.  If I'm parsing a file (that includes newline characters) character by character, using

```
char next = file.get();
```

will the following check ever be true?

```
if (next == '\n')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  It gets the next character from the stream.  It does not skip newlines or whitespace.